# Are vampires vulnerable to crucifixes because of the crucifixion of Jesus?

Tags: christianity, vampires

I wanted to know if the legends of vampires being vulnerable to a crucifix or a cross exist because of what happened to Jesus. Is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126511/what-was-the-first-story-in-which-crucifixes-burned-vampires) might be of interest.

If it's correct that modern vampire folklore largely derives from Stoker, then most likely the answer to your question is yes. [Vampire literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_literature) only seems to predate Dracula by a century and a half, so it doesn't appear that we're really looking at any kind of deep lore here.

Whether in legend or real life, the crucifix is a very powerful sign indeed.

Comment: The cross was a rune called [Naudiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naudiz) long before it became a Christian symbol. The rune means "need, distress".